# Error importing to RethinkDB

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I am getting an error trying to import a json file into RethinkDB on a Google Cloud Compute Instance, and I have no idea what to do with this error. Any help is appreciated. Here is the error:

```
root@my-server-name:~# rethinkdb import -f users_0.json --table test.users
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rethinkdb-import", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('rethinkdb==2.3.0.post1', 'console_scripts', 'rethinkdb-import')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rethinkdb/_import.py", line 929, in main
    import_file(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rethinkdb/_import.py", line 904, in import_file
    pkey = rdb_call_wrapper(conn_fn, "table check", table_check, db, table, options["create_args"], options["force"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rethinkdb/_backup.py", line 78, in rdb_call_wrapper
    return fn(progress, conn, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rethinkdb/_import.py", line 885, in table_check
if not options["quiet"]:
NameError: global name 'options' is not defined
```

The RethinkDB is running on the same VM with Docker. I instantiated it with this command:

```
docker run -i -t -p 8080:8080 -p 28015:28015 -p 29015:29015 rethinkdb
```

Comment: Hey @BenSimmons, you should update your Python driver as this comment describes and try again. Sorry about this bug! https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/5736#issuecomment-215922401

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're using a variable they haven't defined. I pulled the code for that version **2.3.0.post1** from pypi (included the function with the bug below). I also checked version **2.2.0.post2**, and I don't see that bug there, so downgrade that package and you should be fine.

```
def table_check(progress, conn, db, table, create_args, force):
    pkey = None

if db == "rethinkdb":
    raise RuntimeError("Error: Cannot import a table into the system database: 'rethinkdb'")

if db not in r.db_list().run(conn):
    r.db_create(db).run(conn)

if table in r.db(db).table_list().run(conn):
    if not force:
        raise RuntimeError("Error: Table already exists, run with --force if you want to import into the existing table")

    if 'primary_key' in create_args:
        pkey = r.db(db).table(table).info()["primary_key"].run(conn)
        if create_args["primary_key"] != pkey:
            raise RuntimeError("Error: Table already exists with a different primary key")
else:
    if 'primary_key' in create_args:
        pkey = create_args["primary_key"]
    else:
        if not options["quiet"]:
            print("no primary key specified, using default primary key when creating table")
    r.db(db).table_create(table, **create_args).run(conn)

return pkey
```